# PHP: Check SimpleXmlElement for erros

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

Anyone know how can I check the php SimpleXmlElement Object for errors?I mean if is an valid XML file?I have read the manual a lot..but i don't get it!

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-simplexml.html (see the `Error handling` section) SimpleXML will not validate your file, it will only check if it is well-formed and return false if that is not the case.

An alternative is to use the [PHP DOM Class](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), call [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) and either write an own error handler and look at the warnings or just let it print the warnings normally. Since SimpleXML is just a DOM Wrapper you can simply cast it to a DOMDocument and viceversa.

You can also turn the *validateOnParse* property off and then validate it seperately with [`DOMDocument::validate`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php).